# Android SharedPreferences won't save data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

So I have two activities, one contains all elements like RadioButtons, EditText etc, and the other one contains just TextViews on which passed data will be displayed.

That works just fine, the problem starts when I try to save that data. Followed numerous YouTube tutorials and exampes on StackOwerflow, but it just won't save data.

Anyway, here's the code of first activity:

```
RadioGroup radioGrupa;
    RadioButton imperial, metric;
    EditText visinaCM, visinaFT, visinaINC, tezina , bodyfat, tdee, bmi, bmr, ffmi;
    TextView rezultatTDEE, textVisinaCM, textVisinaFI, rezultatTezina, rezultatBMI, rezultatFFMI, rezultatBMR, rezultatBF;
    Button spremiRezultat;
    int onStartCount = 0;



    public void radioStatistikeInputMetric(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.radioStatistikeMetric:
                if (checked)
               // TU OVO SREDI!!!
                    //textVisinaCM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   // visinaCM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //textVisinaFI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //visinaFT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   // visinaINC.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                spremiRezultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppLayoutMain.class);

                                    intent.putExtra("tdeeInput", tdee.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("bodyFatInput", bodyfat.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("tezinaMetricInput", tezina.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("visinaMetricInput", visinaCM.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("bmiInput", bmi.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("bmrInput", bmr.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("ffmiInput", ffmi.getText().toString());

                                startActivity(intent);
                        }
                });
                break;
        }
    }

    public void radioStatistikeInputImperial(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.radioStatistikeImperial:
                if (checked)
                    //textVisinaCM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               // visinaCM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              //  textVisinaFI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             //   visinaFT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             //   visinaINC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    spremiRezultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppLayoutMain.class);
                                intent.putExtra("tdeeInput", tdee.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("bodyFatInput", bodyfat.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("tezinaImperialInput", tezina.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("visinaImperialInputFT", visinaFT.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("visinaImperialInputINC", visinaINC.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("bmiInput", bmi.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("bmrInput", bmr.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("ffmiInput", ffmi.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                break;
        }
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistike_input_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            String inputi = savedInstanceState.getString("INPUTI");
            rezultatTDEE.setText(inputi);
        }

        onStartCount = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
        } else {
            onStartCount = 2;
        }


// RADIO
        radioGrupa = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGrupaStatistike);
        imperial = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioStatistikeImperial);
        metric = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioStatistikeMetric);
//VISINA
        visinaCM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeVisinaCM);
        visinaFT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeVisinaFEET);
        visinaINC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeVisinaINCH);
//TEŽINA
        tezina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeTezina);
//BODYFAT
        bodyfat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeBF);
//TDEE
        tdee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeTDEE);
//BMI
        bmi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeBMI);
//BMR
        bmr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeBMR);
//FFMI
        ffmi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeFFMI);
//BUTTON
        spremiRezultat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStatistikeInputSpremi);
//REZULTATI
        rezultatTDEE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTDEE);
        textVisinaCM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        textVisinaFI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeVisinaFeetInch);
        rezultatTezina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
        rezultatBMI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMI);
        rezultatBMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMR);
        rezultatFFMI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeFFMI);
        rezultatBF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatBodyFat);

    }

    public void save(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("bmi", bmi.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("bmr", bmr.getText().toString());

        editor.commit();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        if (onStartCount > 1) {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);

        } else if (onStartCount == 1) {
            onStartCount++;
        }

    }
```

Sharedpreferences is located in `save` method.

Now here's the code of second activity:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    int onStartCount = 0;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    NavigationView nvDrawer;
    DrawerLayout dlDrawer;
    android.support.v7.widget.CardView karticaStatistike;
    TextView tdeeRezultat, bodyFatRezultat, bmiRezultat, bmrRezultat, ffmiRezultat, tezinaMetricRezultat, visinaMetricRezultat, tezinaImperialRezultat, visinaFTImperialRezultat, visinaINCImperialRezultat, ciljTreningRezultat, razinaTreningRezultat, preporukaTreningRezultat, oneRMPotisakSKlupeRezultat, oneRMCucanjRezultat, oneRMMrtvoDizanjeRezultat, ciljPrehranaRezultat;
    public static final String DEFAULT="N/A";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_layout_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        karticaStatistike = (android.support.v7.widget.CardView) findViewById(R.id.Statiske);


        //  STATISTIKE - PASSAN DATA

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String tdee = intent.getStringExtra("tdeeInput");
        String bf = intent.getStringExtra("bodyFatInput");
        String bmi = intent.getStringExtra("bmiInput");
        String bmr = intent.getStringExtra("bmrInput");
        String ffmi = intent.getStringExtra("ffmiInput");
        String tezinaMetric = intent.getStringExtra("tezinaMetricInput");
        String visinaMetric = intent.getStringExtra("visinaMetricInput");
        String tezinaImperial = intent.getStringExtra("tezinaImperialInput");
        String visinaImperial1 = intent.getStringExtra("visinaImperialInputFT");
        String visinaImperial2 = intent.getStringExtra("visinaImperialInputINC");
        tdeeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTDEE);
        tdeeRezultat.setText(tdee);
        bodyFatRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatBodyFat);
        bodyFatRezultat.setText(bf);
        bmiRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMI);
        bmiRezultat.setText(bmi);
        bmrRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMR);
        bmrRezultat.setText(bmr);
        ffmiRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeFFMI);
        ffmiRezultat.setText(ffmi);
        tezinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
        tezinaMetricRezultat.setText(tezinaMetric);
        visinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        visinaMetricRezultat.setText(visinaMetric);



// SMISLI ŠTA ĆEŠ S OVIM, IZAZIVA KONFLIKT U VISINI I TEŽINI, PROBAJ S NEKIM IFOM
       // tezinaImperialRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
       // tezinaImperialRezultat.setText(tezinaImperial);
        //visinaFTImperialRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        //visinaFTImperialRezultat.setText(visinaImperial1 + "'" +  " " + visinaImperial2 + "''");
        //  STATISTIKE - KRAJ PASSANJA



// TRENING - PASSAN DATA
        String oneRMBench = intent.getStringExtra("oneRMBenchInput");
        String oneRMSquat = intent.getStringExtra("oneRMSquatInput");
        String oneRMDead = intent.getStringExtra("oneRMDeadInput");
        String ciljTreninga = intent.getStringExtra("vrijednostSpinneraCilj");
        String razinaIskustva = intent.getStringExtra("vrijednostSpinneraRazinaIskustva");

        oneRMPotisakSKlupeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultat1RMPotisakSKlupe);
        oneRMPotisakSKlupeRezultat.setText(oneRMBench);
        oneRMCucanjRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultat1RMCucanj);
        oneRMCucanjRezultat.setText(oneRMSquat);
        oneRMMrtvoDizanjeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultat1RMMrtvoDizanje);
        oneRMMrtvoDizanjeRezultat.setText(oneRMDead);

        ciljTreningRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultatCilj);
        ciljTreningRezultat.setText(ciljTreninga);
        razinaTreningRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultatRazinaIskustva);
        razinaTreningRezultat.setText(razinaIskustva);


// PREHRANA - PASSAN DATA

        String prehrana = intent.getStringExtra("vrijednostSpinnera");

        ciljPrehranaRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrehranaCiljRezultat);
        ciljPrehranaRezultat.setText(prehrana);
        tdeeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrehranaTDEE);
        tdeeRezultat.setText(tdee);




        dlDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        dlDrawer.setDrawerListener((DrawerLayout.DrawerListener) drawerToggle);


        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        onStartCount = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
        } else {
            onStartCount = 2;
        }

    }

    public void load(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String bmiSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("bmi", "DEFAULT");
        String bmrSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("bmr", "DEFAULT");

        if (bmiSaved.equals(DEFAULT) || bmrSaved.equals(DEFAULT)){
            Toast.makeText(AppLayoutMain.this, "No Data Was Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(AppLayoutMain.this, "Data Loaded Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bmiRezultat.setText(bmiSaved);
            bmrRezultat.setText(bmrSaved);
    }
```

Sharedpreferences are in `load` method.

I apollogize for large code amount, but I have a lot of data that needs to be displayed and saved.

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: So which toast gets displayed when you run load(View v);

Comment: If there's no entered data it shows the first one

Comment: One thing I see is that you not calling the save method??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

```
....
String tel = editText.getText();
....

SharedPreferences etext = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = etext.edit();
editor.putString("tel", tel);
editor.apply();
```

To retreive:

```
SharedPreferences etext = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
String str = etext.getString("tel", "");
```

Comment: No, constantly getting erros this way

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat

Answer (score 0):

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
.edit().putString("key", StringValue).apply();` to save a String.

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
.getString("key", defaultString);` to get the String. 
 At least for the default preferences.

Answer (score -1):

in second code you have:

```
    else
            Toast.makeText(AppLayoutMain.this, "Data Loaded Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bmiRezultat.setText(bmiSaved);
            bmrRezultat.setText(bmrSaved);
```

i guess it should be like this you need to add the brackets {}:

```
    else {
            Toast.makeText(AppLayoutMain.this, "Data Loaded Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bmiRezultat.setText(bmiSaved);
            bmrRezultat.setText(bmrSaved); 
         }
```

also why you add "DEFAULT" as string in the default value it won't be initialized as "N/A" like this just replace it with

```
sharedPreferences.getString("bmr", DEFAULT);
```

*I assumed you call the save function on click from the XML with some kind of button in your design.

Comment: Just did all that, I have a button that calls that save onClick, but it won't save data. If I kill the app, data gets deleted

Comment: the store and retrieve code you are using is right, just double check any other code that could lead to this issue. try a smoke test just set the text as static string and print it in a toast in the second activity.

Comment: Braces are on their places.